# Calculating Imaginary Number

Tags: complex-numbers

Is this step-by-step computation correct?
\begin{align}
\frac {3i^{30}-i^{19}}{2i-1} &= \frac {3(i^{2})^{15}-(i^{2})^{9}i}{2i-1} \\
&= \frac {3(-1)^{15}-(-1)^{9}i}{2i-1} \\
&= \frac {-3+i}{2i-1} \\
&= \frac {-3+i}{2i-1} \times \frac {2i+1}{2i+1} \\
&= \frac {-6i-5+i}{-5} \\
&= \frac {-5i-5}{-5} \\
&= i+1.
\end{align}

Comment: Now correct....  But could be done in far fewer steps.

Comment: Looks about right to me

Comment: @ZnikDzulqarnain What is the question?

Comment: the answer $i+1$ is the question

Comment: You can always check with an online calculator like wolfram for these (although it won't check the middle steps, of course). https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3(i%5E30)-i%5E19)%2F(2i-1)

Comment: Thank you guys for correcting me , english wasnt my native language , so sorry for that

Comment: @David G.Stork i would like to know how

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Far fewer steps meaning skipping a few? As far as I can see, surely this is the process that goes through your head when calculating it?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Why do you always make comments/answers like "the answer is ____"?  Such comments do not tell us anything about how to solve the problem, especially if we've already got the answer.  Please consider being more constructive.

Comment: It could be shortened in the writing, at the expense of doing some steps mentally, but I don't think there is fundamentally shorter than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate method is to take advantage of $i^{4} = 1$ in such a way that $i^{19} = i^{4 \cdot 4 + 3} = (i^{4})^{4} \, i^{3} = i^{3} = - i$ and $i^{30} = i^{4 \cdot 7 + 2} = i^{2} =-1$. This leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{3i^{30}-i^{19}}{2i-1} &= \frac{i - 3}{2i -1} = \frac{(i-3)(2i +1)}{4 i^{2} - 1} = i+1. 
\end{align}

Comment: I did it the same way and it comes out right.